# Example ordering in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

IMO this is an essential feature. These are not answers that should be ordered by the merit or quality of the answer. Examples within the documentation should be sequential, building in complexity. For example two documentation topics I created:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1686/basic-subsetting#t=2016072122023513926

or

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1669/overview-of-data-structures#t=201607212212259295288